# Sitecore MVC is not working on Preview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

We are using Sitecore 7.2 with ASP.NET MVC. The mvc page works with now issue when viewing directly via URL or previewing from Publish > Preview.

However, following exception is thrown when we try to preview from Presentation > Preview.

> The controller for path '/mysite/Home/test' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Sitecore.Mvc.Diagnostics.ExceptionWrapper: The
>   controller for path '/mysite/Home/test' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ExceptionWrapper: The controller for path '/mysite/Home/test' was not
>   found or does not implement IController.]
>
> [ControllerCreationException: Could not create controller: 'Home'. ]
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +371
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +270    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +147
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +12272591    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Not sure why but sitecore seems to pass different query string parameters for Presentation > Preview vs. Publish > Preview.

If someone can print to right direct to fix this will be great.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but this might give you some insight in to the differing behaviour: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518421/difference-between-two-different-preview-mode-in-sitecore

Answer (score 0):

I did not worked with MVC in Sitecore, still if controller is referring to Home Item you should check this settings in Web.Config

```
<site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
```

You will need to check **rootPath** and **startItem**.